# How to center horizontally two labels?

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder, autolayout, uilabel

I have pretty straightforward requirements where two labels must be centered horizontally. So, I have selected them and chose Editor->align->center horizontally. Then added top space to container constraint to both of them. I also need the labels to shrink/grow regarding content size. However, IB shows errors and several warnings. I could make the labels shrink/grow just by adding pin between them (horizontal space) but they will not be centered in that case. Here are the screenshots:

[image]

here are the errors and warnings:

[image]

**UPDATE** theraven gave an interesting suggestion to use dummy view for centering it horizontally and pinning two labels to it. I have removed all existing constraints, added this dummy view and center X + center Y constraints to it. Then pined two labels to it (added horizontal space constraints). However, I still get a bunch of errors and warnings:

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE2** Just updating the question, but still no valid answer found. @Theraven workaround works for iPhone4, iPhone4S, iPhone5 and iPhone5S, however it's not real centering but rather a  workaround. Therefore for iPhone6 and iPhone6 Plus it doesn't work as leading and trailing spaces will be fixed and won't automatically resize for larger width.

Comment: `straightforward requirements where two labels must be centered horizontally` - do you want to have your view divided into two parts (left and right) and then the labels centered in each part?

Comment: @ArkadiuszHolko yes.

Comment: This is still ambiguous. Do you want equal space between left edge<->first label <-> second label <->right edge. 
Or equal space between left edge<->first label <->centre of screen, and centre of screen<->second label<->right edge.
The difference being the space in the centre will be greater in the second scenario. Once you clarify I'll fixup my answer.

Answer (score 13):

What you could do is add both labels to another view, like a container view. Then you need to center this one horizontally and add the necessary constraints. 
To add the containing `UIView`, you can select both labels, go to `Editor -> Embed In -> View`.

Then you would need to add constraints to make the containing view fit the two labels. So something like this:

First Label (left one):

- Leading Space to Superview
- Top and bottom Space to Superview
- Horizontal spacing to the next Label

Second Label:

- Trailing space to superview
- Top and Bottom to superview (or align top with the first one)

Then the containing view should resize as to fit both labels. Then all you need to do is add the top offset constraint for this container view and a horizontal alignment it in the parent view.

This way, the containing view will grow as much as it needs to fit both labels and the space between them and will always be centered in the parent view.

I took a screenshot of my test constraints in case it helps you more.

[image: The constraints for the left side label]

[image: Right-side label]

Hope this was what you were looking for.

Comment: Yes, it's valid approach but requires redundant containerView. This is how I did similar stuff long before auto layout appeared.

Answer (score 5):

To solve this use a blank UIView in between your two labels and center it horizontally. Then pin the two labels either side of the centered blank view. It is common convention to use spacer views like this in auto-layout.

Comment: Thanks, tried your suggestion but with no luck. See updated answer.

Comment: @TJ theraven answer works only by pinning with constant offsets (adding trailing space to centered separatorView (for left view), and adding leading space to centered separator (for right view). This workaround works for iPhone4, iPhone4S, iPhone5 and iPhone5S, however it's not real centering, it's just a workaround. Therefore for iPhone6 and iPhone6 Plus is doesn't work as leading and trailing spaces are constants and won't automatically resize.

Comment: @Centurion you may be able to use left and right justification to get around that problem

Comment: Very clever solution :)

Answer (score 1):

I really don't like the idea of adding another view just for sake of estethic.

Another alternative is to horizontally-center the left view, and horizzontally space the right view of an amout X with the left one.

Then to give the horizontally-align contraint of the first view a negative value equal to the first view width plus half the views distance. Or use multipliers as said in a previous comment.

But this only works with fixed width views i guess.

Comment: How  "to horizontally space the right view of an amout X with the left one"?

Answer (score 1):

Use centered `UIStackView` as a container for two labels with a spacing required.

Answer (score 0):

**I didn't really understand what you wish to do.**

The error you get (in the first screen shot) is that you are missing constraint for the x position of the labels.

For UILabel you must have constraint both for y and for x position regarding to the container view, when you selected them both and chose Editor->align->center horizontally, you just say that label1.center.x = label2.center.x. 
You still need to say where they will be in the container view, you added the top space to container, so you do have the y position, but you didn't say where the x position should be.

You said

> I have pretty straightforward requirements where two labels must be centered horizontally

But where they should be in respect to their container?

thanks

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Thanks! I just started today, and I really wanted to just leave a comment, but I couldn't because I don't have enough reputation.. But I think that my answer still has some value, because part of the question was about the errors he gets.. anyway I get what you are saying, thanks!

Comment: @oren Please read the question first. Imagine you split the screen in half  vertically (left half screen and right half screen), and you need left label would be centered horizontally in left half screen, and right label would be centered horizontally in right half screen. A good answer is the one that you have already tried by yourself.

Comment: Ok, I just did something like this. Do you know the property 'multiplier'? It can help you, you can set the right label 'center horizontally in container' (with constant 0) and set its multiplier to 3/2, the left one is the same but with multiplier 1/2. that should keep your labels as want want them horizontally...

Answer (score 0):

Using spacer views is the best possible solution I could figure out, even though it looks ugly for the developer. The user wouldn't even know what's going on behind the scenes and once you have the spacer `UIView`, you can always reuse it.